# Angular - set null items in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Why is this code working only once?
When i reset an item the entire app freezes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.products = ["Milk", "Bread", "Cheese"];
    $scope.addItem = function () {
        $scope.products.push($scope.addMe);
    }    
    $scope.resetItem = function (x) {
        $scope.products[x]="";
    }
});
</script>

<div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in products">{{x}}<span ng-click="resetItem($index)">×</span></li>
  </ul>
  <input ng-model="addMe">
  <button ng-click="addItem()">Add</button>
</div>

<p>Click the x to reset an item</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I've also tryed with ng-click='x = "" ' but it doesn't work.
So, how can I set a null value to an item in this array?

Comment: What's the stacktrace in the console ?

Comment: I don't need to remove, but to set null.

Comment: `""` is not `null`

Comment: @epascarello, less philosophy, more help.

Comment: Just pointing out the fact.... Welcome to the site, and remember we are taking time out of our day to help you for free. I am willing to put you on my trash list of people not to help. ;) And I already gave an answer. If it does not meet your needs, than maybe the question should state that you need the item to be in the array with an empty string.

Comment: @YounesM Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=x%20in%20products&p1=string%3A&p2=
    at VM679 angular.min.js:6
    at VM679 angular.min.js:280
    at Object.fn (VM679 angular.min.js:130)
    at r.$digest (VM679 angular.min.js:131)
    at b.$apply (VM679 angular.min.js:134)
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (VM679 angular.min.js:254)
    at If (VM679 angular.min.js:35)
    at HTMLSpanElement.d (VM679 angular.min.js:35)

Comment: Than track by the index as the one answer shows.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For future reference it is a good idea to include  any stacktrack or error messages you encounter within the question when you ask it (or edit it and add it to the question later). That way people can help answer your question better and anyone searching for the same error in future can find the question easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `track by $index` in ng repeat to remove the duplicate.

Also use `splice` to remove the item from an array

```js
var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.products = ["Milk", "Bread", "Cheese"];
    $scope.addItem = function () {
        $scope.products.push($scope.addMe);
    }    
    $scope.resetItem = function (x) {
         $scope.products.splice(x,1);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in products track by $index">{{x}}<span ng-click="resetItem($index)">×</span></li>
  </ul>
  <input ng-model="addMe">
  <button ng-click="addItem()">Add</button>
</div>

<p>Click the x to reset an item</p>
```

Comment: The error was that I created duplicate when i set the second string empty. I solved with "track by $index", thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove an item. You can remove it from the array with [`splice(index, numberOfItemsToRemove)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
$scope.products.splice(x, 1)
```